# Backing Up Cubeworld Character

Tags: cube-world

I have just recently purchased CubeWorld and I do have to say it is an awesome game. Upon purchasing I decided to upgrade my computer with a new motherboard and CPU and I therefore had to reformat the hard drive and re install the OS.

I just presumed that the characters would be saved to the account but apparently they're not. I spent 10 hours building up a character only to find that it doesn't save to the cube world account. Is there a way of backing up these characters? Also if backing up is possible does that mean people are freely able to share their characters with one another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cube world characters and saves are only stored on your PC, in the directory where Cube World is installed. They are not stored online.

Backing up characters is done in the same way as backing up anything else. Locate the file you want to back up- the saves folder- then copy it and save it somewhere else such as a removable hard drive.

Comment: Thanks, I was just checking to make sure that the characters could be backed up. I do believe characters should be stored on a server somewhere so that they are accessible via any computer using the same account.